# How can I reposition this dialog?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5dialog

hey guys :) How can i reposition and resize this dialog? I tried it with the style tag, but nothing happened. I want it to reposition it permanently to a specific position...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The dialog is automatically placed at a position. It always opens there, but I need to reposition and resize it. I tried it with style=" position:absolute; top/right and so on" but nothing worked. I want it to open at the right corner with a different size, for expample. How do I place it there?

```js
(function() {  
    var dialog = document.getElementById('arbeitsauftrag-window');  
    document.getElementById('arbeitsauftrag').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.show();  
    };  
    document.getElementById('arbeitsauftrag-exit').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.close();  
    };  
})();
```

```html
<dialog id="arbeitsauftrag-window" style="position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">  
    <button id="arbeitsauftrag-exit">Fenster schließen. </button> 
</dialog>
<button id="arbeitsauftrag">Open Dialog</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #arbeitsauftrag-window{
  position:absolute;
  left:1500px;
  right:0px;
  background:grey;
}
```

codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pbEdME

Answer (score 0):

To resize, there are extra padding given around the button, you can provide explicit padding CSS property to the dialog or button to resize it.
You can set the opening position with the following code.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", [350,100] );
```

Comment: Yea, its working. But the dialog is automatically placed at a position. It always opens there, but I need to reposition and resize it. I tried it with style=" position:absolute; top/right and so on" but nothing worked. I want it to open at the right corner with a different size, for expample. How do I place it there?

Comment: despite the jquery tag, this is not a jquery dialog - I removed the tag from the question

Comment: ok, any idea what library is used to show this dialog, maybe we can the documentation of that library for the solution.

Comment: there's no library - it's just HTML5 and CSS

Answer (score 0):

May help .. You need to set `left: auto;`

```js
(function() {  
    var dialog = document.getElementById('arbeitsauftrag-window');  
    document.getElementById('arbeitsauftrag').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.show();  
    };  
    document.getElementById('arbeitsauftrag-exit').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.close();  
    };  
})();
```

```html
<dialog id="arbeitsauftrag-window" style="position:absolute; top:5px; right:0; left: auto; height : 200px;width : 200px;">  
    <button id="arbeitsauftrag-exit">Fenster schließen. </button> 
</dialog>
<button id="arbeitsauftrag">Open Dialog</button>
```